# The meaning of the sentence "Fortunately/Wisely, she consults her lawyer regularly."

Tags: tenses, present-tense, subjunctive-mood, should, indicative

In Quirk's **A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language** Section 8.128 (page 624): it says

> Fortunately/Wisely, she consults her lawyer regularly. [1]
>
> = It is fortunate/wise that she consult(s)/should consult her lawyer regularly. [2]

I think that *she consults her lawyer regularly* in [1] is **simple present tense**, which means it is a fact, a habitual fact in this clause.

But the subordinate clause *she consult/should consult her lawyer regularly* in [2] is **present subjunctive or putative should**, which means it is not a fact. In reality, she may or may not consult her lawyer regularly.

So could anyone please help to figure it out why [1] and [2] are semantically equivalent?

I am not a native speaker of English and I think Quirk's book is very great. I will appreciate it if you have any ideas about this question.

PS: Regarding the meaning of the symbol **equal sign =**, in the book ACGEL itself page(ix), **Abbreviations and symbols** section, just immediately before **Chapter 1** (page 1),  it displays that **equal sign =** means *semantically equivalent*.

Comment: Consider: "It is strange that she should react/have reacted like that."

Comment: @fev's sentences work well.  But I agree that only the indicative sounds natural with the ACGEL rewrite nowadays. (It's a rather dated text.)

Comment: "It is wise that she *consult* her lawyer regularly" amounts to a suggestion: She better consult her lawyer regularly. Sounds like subjunctive to me.

Comment: They are not semantically equivalent. [1] asserts that she does something; [2] asserts the wisdom or fortunateness of her doing something. They have different truth conditions and different entailments. [2] is implied by [1]. If  _consults_ is used, then [2] also implies [1], but otherwise it doesn't. I don't think Quirk means "=" to be taken as "is semantically equivalent" in any rigorous sense.

Comment: I agree with @ColinFine. The two sentences express different meanings and are not semantically equivalent.

Comment: @ColinFine Thanks for your reply. In the book ACGEL page(ix), just immediately before chapter 1, **Abbreviations and symbols**,  it lists *= semantically equivalent*.

Comment: @kevin4fly He's wrong then. They aren't.

Comment: @Colin Fine - Could you give an answer? Comments are for clarification of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Yosef. I read into the use of "fortunately/wisely" as the subjective opinion of the writer/narrator and the subjunctive mood can correctly be used to capture opinion. In that case, I do understand the equivalency, but only insofar as it is the opinion of the writer/narrator. In this case, it doesn't mean it's not a fact; it's almost like an "if/then" statement.

Ex: To the narrator, if the woman consults her lawyer regularly, then she is wise. Additionally, if the woman consults her lawyer regularly, then it is fortunate (for her, presumably). Since the woman does the exact thing the narrator thinks would/could/should be fortunate and wise, the woman meets the criteria for fortune and wisdom and *is* fortunate and wise. I get what Quirk means, but it might not be the most elegant way to explain the equivalency.

I could also be totally off-base.